# GLM: Can't compile anymore

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, clang, glm-math

Does anybody use [this library](http://glm.g-truc.net/index.html) anymore?

Worked great for me last year but now my code isn't compiling:

(on MinGW with GCC 4.6.1):

```
In file included from ../include/glm/./core/func_packing.hpp:190:0,
                 from ../include/glm/glm.hpp:103,
                 from SmoothRenderer.cpp:11:
../include/glm/./core/func_packing.inl: In function 'glm::detail::uint32 glm::packUnorm4x8(const glm::detail::tvec4<float>&)':
../include/glm/./core/func_packing.inl:84:17: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token
../include/glm/./core/func_packing.inl:84:17: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
../include/glm/./core/func_packing.inl:84:17: error: expected ';' before 'round'
../include/glm/./core/func_packing.inl:85:26: error: 'D' was not declared in this scope
../include/glm/./core/func_packing.inl: In function 'glm::detail::tvec4<float> glm::unpackUnorm4x8(const uint32&)':
../include/glm/./core/func_packing.inl:94:38: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
../include/glm/./core/func_packing.inl:99:4: error: 'D' was not declared in this scope
```

This is with newest version 0.9.4.3.

Similar problems on my Mac with latest clang:

```
In file included from SmoothRenderer.cpp:10:
In file included from ../include/glm/glm.hpp:103:
In file included from ../include/glm/./core/func_packing.hpp:190:
../include/glm/core/func_packing.inl:84:33: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
                detail::uint8 D((detail::uint8)round(clamp(v.w, 0.0f, 1.0f) * 255.0f));
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
./util.h:330:15: note: expanded from macro 'D'
# define D(x) x
              ^
In file included from SmoothRenderer.cpp:10:
In file included from ../include/glm/glm.hpp:103:
In file included from ../include/glm/./core/func_packing.hpp:190:
../include/glm/core/func_packing.inl:85:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'D'
                return detail::uint32((D << 24) | (C << 16) | (B << 8) | A);
                                       ^
../include/glm/core/func_packing.inl:99:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'D'
                        D * 1.0f / 255.0f);
                        ^
../include/glm/core/func_packing.inl:94:30: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
                detail::uint32 D((p >> 24) & Mask8);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~
./util.h:330:15: note: expanded from macro 'D'
# define D(x) x
              ^
In file included from SmoothRenderer.cpp:10:
In file included from ../include/glm/glm.hpp:108:
In file included from ../include/glm/./core/func_noise.hpp:85:
../include/glm/core/func_noise.inl:125:33: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
                detail::tvec4<T> const D(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0);
                                              ^
../include/glm/core/func_noise.inl:125:27: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
                detail::tvec4<T> const D(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0);
                                        ^
                                        ;
```

This is a header-only library. Things like this shouldn't be happening...

I am only using this for some 4x4 matrix multiplication and inversion. Since the rest of my app uses LAPACK extensively there is nothing i really need that glm does. But I hate when my code which I try to make very portable randomly breaks like this.

Comment: I just realized. There may be a macro conflict as I do remember in the interim I had made a change to my debug macro renaming it from `DEBUG` to `D`. This is horrible.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it turned out to be an issue with the `D` macro. Damn it, answering my question 4 minutes after asking it. That's the beauty of explaining a problem. Half the time that's enough.

This is one more reason to avoid using the preprocessor. Mad errors. Though, to its credit, clang was nice enough to not only mention that something seemed iffy with a macro defined elsewhere, it even copied it in there to show me.